# How I can open Outllook with Recipient in a ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook, sendmail

I want about a ASP.NET Application open Outlook with the Recipient without the mail is send. 
Only open Outlook with the Recipient.

I want test it for a other application and in my test I use a Textbox with the Recipient text and a Button openOutlook.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Outlook is the default email client installed, you can use the mailto prefix in an anchor tag :

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com">Send email to user@example.com</a>
```

Otherwise, your choices may be limited as your web server has no way of opening specific applications on client computers. You may have to develop an ActiveX or Java applet, but this would really be overkill.

Comment: But How I can do this if I click on the <asb:Button >